# method to solve a Second order of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y''(x)+\left(\dfrac 2 x +\dfrac x 2\right)y'(x)+ \dfrac 3 2 y(x)=0$$

Can anyone help me by telling me a method to solve this kind of differential equations ? 
I tried Cauchy Euler method, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The term $\frac 2x+\frac x2=\frac{x^2+4}{2x}$ gave me the idea to define $y=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} z$ which makes the equation
$$e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}\frac{ \left(4-x^2\right) z'(x)+2 x z''(x)}{2 x}=0$$ So, consider 
$$\left(4-x^2\right) z'+2 x z''=0$$ Now, reduce the order $u=z'$ to get
$$\left(4-x^2\right) u+2 x u'=0$$ which is separable and  leads to
$$u=z'=\frac{c_1}{x^2} e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\implies z=c_1 \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}}{x}\right)+c_2$$

Comment: Thanks. what is erfi ?

Comment: @Mike. The imaginary error function. Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

Comment: +1 Claude for  your nice solution

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I really appreciate your help. There was given two conditions that I do not understand how to apply them. First one, limit of y(x)= 0 when x goes to infinity. Second one, the integral from 0 to infinity of square x multiply by y(x)= k/4pi. Please help me

Comment: @Mike Please update the question to include all the conditions

Comment: @Mike. As Dylan commented, when you ask help for a problem, give all of it.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''(x)+(\dfrac 2x +\dfrac x2)y'(x)+ (\dfrac32) y(x)=0$$
Multiply by $2x^2$
$$(2x^2y')'+(x^3y)'=0$$
Integrate
$$2x^2y'+x^3y=K$$
$$y'+\frac x2y=\frac K {2x^2}$$
$$y'+\frac x2y=\frac C{x^2}$$
You can try to solve the first ode ( It may not be expressed with elementary functions)
$$(ye^{x^2/4})'=e^{x^2/4}\frac C{x^2}$$
$$y=C_1e^{-x^2/4} \int \frac {e^{x^2/4}}{x^2}dx+C_2e^{-x^2/4}$$

Comment: Nice manipulation ! $\to +1$

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici yours is also nice and more complete ..

Comment: thank you all of you.. I will consider that next time.

Comment: yw @Mike.........